# Scala finding elements in big (30MB) xml files

Tags: xml, scala, maven

I have a 30MB big XML files and want to find a couple of elements in it.

The file is an effective pom.xml and I want to get all dependencies (name,group,version), submodules and the parent from it. You can look at such a file using

```
mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=test.xml
```

For my file of 26MB, scala's XML.load* results in java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

What can I do besides increasing heap-space ?

TIA, bastl.

Comment: Can you say a little more about the elements you need to find?  In general, if the _entire file_ was the one element you're looking for, and you care about the content of that element, you might need to load the entire file to check that the element was what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Daniels point, I'm biased anyway of course, Scales Xml provides what you need for higher level pull parsing.  Sometimes a full blown tree parse simply isn't a good match and pull parsing traditionally forces too much management on the developer.  Scales aims to make this simpler via iteratees and a notion of path.

If you can identify the paths you need then Scales will pull out mini trees for each item.  This works via combining the results of iteratees (one iteratee for each path) and allowing the user to fold over each occurrence.

This runs in constant space, only limited by what objects you keep during the parse, but is slower than a tree based parse.  (Scales requires around 200-220MB of heap to process a 30MB tree - but can be reduced to 170-180 if the document is easy to optimise - see [memory optimisation](http://scala-scales.googlecode.com/svn/sites/scales/scales-xml_2.9.2/0.3-RC7/MemoryOptimisation.html#Memory_Consumption_During_Parsing)  for more details)

See [the Pull Parsing docs for examples](http://scala-scales.googlecode.com/svn/sites/scales/scales-xml_2.9.2/0.3-RC7/RepeatedSections.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [pull parsing](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/xml/pull/package.html), where XML elements are viewed as a sequence of events (open tag `a`, open tag `i`, text, close tag `i`, ...).

This avoids storing the entire file in memory.

I have used it on XML files of several hundreds of MB without any major problem. (Of course, as Rex points out in a comment, if the elements you want to recover are themselves huge, there is no obvious way around it.)

The pull parser is not as convenient as the "regular" one (or [Anti-XML](http://anti-xml.org/)) because it does not give you a tree. Instead, you have to manage state to track where you are in the document.

Here is a self contained example that shows how to extract all internal links on the Wikipedia page for Scala:

```
import scala.xml.Text
import scala.xml.pull._
import scala.io.Source

val src = Source.fromURL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)")

val reader = new XMLEventReader(src)

val Internal = """/wiki/([\w_]*)""".r

var inLink = false
var linksTo = ""

for(event <- reader) { 
  event match { 
    case EvElemStart(_, "a", meta, _) => meta("href") match { 
      case Text(Internal(href)) =>
        linksTo = href
        inLink = true
      case _ => 
    } 
    case EvText(txt) if inLink => println(txt + " --> " + linksTo)
    case EvElemEnd(_, "a") => inLink = false
    case _ => ; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I did not knew that parser came with Scala. I think the name was wrongly chosen by the Scala team. It looks like a push-parser (where events are pushed by the library) rather than a real pull parser like Stax, where you pull information from the XML.

Comment: It's a regular expression. In Scala you can [use them as patterns](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex) in pattern matching, which is what happens in my code example (`case Text(Internal(href))`).

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, Scala's standard library's xml doesn't cut it. You can use the pull parser, but it's hardly practical. Instead, I'd use [Scales](http://code.google.com/p/scala-scales/) (seeing as Anti-XML isn't an improvement either -- I thought they had iteratee-based selectors, but I couldn't find them).